# Admin IOU L3 switch

Tags: switch, cisco-ios, gns3

Problem with IOU l2 switch
By  Konstantinos Dimos

July 31, 2022 at 3:12 UTC

Hi, under Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, gns3 and local server I am trying to manage switch IOU L3 switch, although at the begining I was able, now I get the followinf console output:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Documentation mentions I have to apply many enter before I prompt bt nothing.

Any suggestion?

Comment: That looks like correct output

Comment: I do not get prompt